# How can I resolve this issue with Acumatica Box IDs?

Tags: acumatica

When creating Shipments for SOs with Acumatica, it is coming up with an error related to the 'SO Package Detail':

> 'Box ID' cannot be found in the system

Does anyone have any insight as to why this would occur? I had previously thought it may be due to the Box IDs not being listed under the Carrier used, but this did not resolve the error when I added these under the Carriers. These Box IDs are present within Acumatica. It is possibly related to the UOM, or another variable tied to the Box IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Box Id's to the packages tab for the Ship Via Codes in Acumatica.

1. Log into Acumatica, Navigate to Distribution, then click on Shipments.
2. Click the Configuration tab and select Ship Via Codes.
3. Select the Ship Via you are using, and click on the packages tab for the Ship Via.
4. Add the Box ID's you wish to use with this Ship Via
5. Save the Ship Via Code record

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one or more of your Stock Items has an invalid Box ID.  Review all the Stock Items on the Sales Order(s) you are attempting to ship and verify they all have valid Box ID's.